# Не работает калькулятор в IE6-8

Tags: javascript

Добрый день товарищи!
Друг попросил помочь с калькулятором на сайте http://srubdacha.ru/shop/product/b44
Его нужно приспособить к IE которые раньше 9 версии. Он в основном на jQuery, но видимо из-за каких-то функций из js, не удаётся старичку IE посчитать. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Там есть такой кусок кода

```
diametr   = $("select#diametr :selected").val().replace(/,/,".");
kind         = $("select#kind :selected").val().replace(/,/,".");
...
anisept = Math.round( (diametr*1) * (anisept*1));
```

Похоже, есть две проблемы: все эти переменные нужно обьявлять с помощью var и в параметре raplace почему-то оказались слеши вокруг запятой. Надо что-то вроде

```
var diametr   = $("select#diametr :selected").val().replace(',',".");
var kind         = $("select#kind :selected").val().replace(',',".");
...
var anisept = Math.round( (diametr*1) * (anisept*1));
```

Comment: Спасибо, в IE8 заработало, в остальных IE6-7, пишет undefined